# Recursive Function Looping Through Array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am having a lot of issues running into a recursive function while trying to loop through an array.

So I am looping through an array (area * 2) times. What I mean by this is if I have a 100x100 array, I am looping through it 20,000 times (100 * 100 * 2).
In the loop, if it finds a value that doesn't equal one, it assigns it to one. 
I have all of that all working but Eclipse will not let me run it due to a StackOverflow.

```
public static void checkPos() {
    while(canrun) {
        if(x < Canvas.length - 1) {
            x++;
        } else {
            x = 0;
            if(y < Canvas.length - 1) {
                y++;
            } else {
                y = 0;
            }
        }
        if(Canvas[x][y] != 0) {
            filled++;
            Assign(x, y);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void Assign(int x, int y) {
    Canvas[x][y] = 1;
    if(filled < spots) {//ERROR POINTING HERE
        checkPos();
    } else {
        printObj();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Any help or a point in the right direction will help.

Comment: Solution: don't use recursion. Instead use a stack.

Comment: The stack in Java is very small (between 5 000 and 7 000 recursive calls if my memory is right)

Comment: You have cyclical dependencies.

Comment: Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Recursion is implemented using...a stack. Did you mean use iteration? That was the solution I suggested yesterday. (This question is a slightly modified dup of OP's original question) Sorry buddy, but I'm going to have to vote to close. Since you still appear to be struggling I'll try to address your issues in more detail.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi I did not see that you updated your post on my previous thread to further explain my problem in detail. Thank you for your help. I am just getting confused with all the loops inside of loops that I have. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand what happens when you use a recursive function, a function lives in the stack untill it returns a value, when you use recursive function you call same function over and over but you do so within each one, which means your floating the stack into a size you might not be able to get from the OS, in your case which is quite simple I would advise to remove the recursion and use it all on one loop, you can use,
    Canvas[x][y] = 1;
    if(...){
        break;
    }
    else{
        return bla bla
    }

inside the original loop.